# Download Problems

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, apt, chromium, pi-store

I bought an Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and I cannot, in anyway, install the Pi Store or Chromium. I have only been able to somehow install the Google App, which wasn't what I was exactly looking for. I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install pistore
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pistore
sudo apt-get install chromium
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Every time, it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package pistore
```

or

```
E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
```

How do I install these packages?

Comment: I've seen other people with similar problems, but saw no satisfactory answers. Please help me out with this annoying problem!

Comment: Please consider this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error and try to avoid all-caps rants.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a download problem - except that what you are trying to download doesn't exist.

Pistore is defunct https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=130379

What exactly are you trying to install? There is (or was) a  chromium-browser and Chromium OS for which you need to download an image (I have never used either).

`sudo apt search chromium` will show any candidates.

Comment: +1, but `apt search` doesn't require sudo permissions. Best practice would be to avoid it when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Chromium 49 with Chromium Store if you follow this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195 .

Comment: Tthere is no package for chroium browser in Jessie which is what the OP will be running on a Pi3

Comment: Ok. My fault. I just checked that there isn't chromium in repository

Answer (score -1):

Use `sudo apt-get install update` first. Then, retry the commands you listed.